# SQL Anywhere/ASP.NET - using SQLDataSource with output parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql

The database I am using is SQL Anywhere from Sybase. v 11.0.1

I have the following stored procedure to insert a row. I
return the @@identity variable with a select statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "DBA"."Portal_InsertHeader"( in
theimi integer, in theUser long varchar, in
theNextServiceDate date)
RESULT( ident integer )
BEGIN

insert into
InvoiceCreditHeader(imi,createdby,nextServiceDate)
values(theimi,theUser,theNextServiceDate);

select @@identity;

END
```

In my ASP.NET web app I have the following in the
SQLDataSource. I am using the output type in the last
parameter.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsHeader" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MSPortal %>"
ProviderName="<%$
ConnectionStrings:MSPortal.ProviderName %>"
InsertCommand="Call
Portal_InsertHeader(?,?,?)"
InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="IMI" Type="Int32" />
<asp:Parameter Name="USER" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter Name="NextServiceDate"
Type="DateTime" />
<asp:Parameter direction="Output"
name="HeaderID" type="Int32" />
</InsertParameters>
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"
DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When I call the .Insert method the row is inserted fine, but
when I try to check the Output parameter in the "Inserted"
method I get a null value.

So what do I need to change to get access to the output
variable in the ASP.NET code?

Comment: When this executes I get an error "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid."                                Protected Sub sqldsHeader_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e     As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles sqldsHeader.Inserted
        If (e.Exception Is Nothing) Then

            Me.hfHeaderNum.Value = e.Command.Parameters("HeaderID").Value

        End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a parroter in the stored procedure with the inout keyword. Using just "out" didn't seem to do it but all worked as expected when I changes it to "inout"

Answer (score 0):

Did you just reference the name wrong?

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="HeaderID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: No. In the Inserted event i reference the correct variable, but it contains DBNUll.

Comment: Ok.  I would also double check to make sure the DB side of things is actually returning the @@identity properly.  I would run the query with a fake insert and do a print of the identity to see if it really is saving it.